# Inject service into guard in Nest.JS

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I have KeysModule, which can be used to add or remove API keys. I need these keys to protect some routes from unauthorized access. 
To protect these routes I have created ApiGuard:

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ApiGuard implements CanActivate {

async canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.headers.api_key;
  }
}
```

And then I use it in route:

```
 @Get('/protected')
 @UseGuards(ApiGuard)
 async protected(@Headers() headers: Api) {
   const key = await this.ks.findKey({ key: headers.api_key });
   if (!key || !key.active) return 'Invalid Key';
   return 'Your API key works';
 }
```

Where ks is KeyService used to check if key is correct or not.
This solution works, but is stupid. I have to copy and paste some lines of code everywhere I want to use this guard (I mean lines in route).

I have tried to to move all logic to ApiGuard, but there I have got error, that KeyService cannot be injected to ApiGuard class. To explain, I have KeyService in providers in KeysModule, but ApiGuard is globally used.

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To inject service in guard.You can create a global module.

```
// ApiModule
import {Module,Global} from '@nestjs/common';
import {KeyService} from '../';

@Global()
@Module({
    providers: [ KeyService ],
    exports: [KeyService]
})
export class ApiModule {}
```

Then inject service into guard like this

```
// guard
export class ApiGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(@Inject('KeyService') private readonly KeyService) {}
}
 async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    // your code
    throw new ForbiddenException();
  }
```

Now the problem can be solved.But I have another problem.I want to inject something into service but got this error:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthGuard (?, +). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the current context.

And here is my solution:

To Inject other dependency in KeyService,like [nestjs docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards) say.

> global guards registered from outside of any module (with useGlobalGuards() as in the example above) cannot inject dependencies since this is done outside the context of any module.

This is their sample：

```
// app.module.js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: RolesGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

It worked.Now I can use guard global without dependency error.

Comment: do you know a way to set guard on a module but on a particular controller

Comment: You can add the @UseGuards(GuardName) decorator to a specific route in the controller. That will only apply the guard to that method.

Answer (score 24):

As of NestJS v8 it seems injecting the service as answered by zsoca in the accepted answer doesn't work anymore.

The working solution for NestJS 8 is by providing a class reference instead of a string:

```js
  constructor(@Inject(KeyService) private keyService: KeyService) {}
```

Comment: You best! Save my life)

Comment: Thanks, I wasted so much time on this!

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it's too late, but I ran the same issue and find a solution. Maybe there is a better one, but it's working properly for me:

Define KeysModule as a global module, you can check how to do it in nestjs docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/modules

After You can do this:

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ApiGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(
@Inject('KeyService')
private readonly ks
) {}

const key = await this.ks.findKey();

"YOUR_CODE_HERE..."

}
```

Hope it's help to you or somebody who will stuck with this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can inject a service in a guard like in any object annotated with `Injectable`.
If your ApiGuard need KeyService you have two choices:

- Add ApiGuard in a module which import KeysModule. Then import the created module to use ApiGuard globally
- Add ApiGuard in KeysModule and export it.

Answer (score 2):

Services used in the guard must be exported in its module. Providing service is not enough!

Answer (score 2):

Nestjs Guard was designed to let you interpose processing logic at exactly the right point in the request/response cycle and this was treated as a normal instance in Nestjs DI Container.

So whenever it has dependencies wherever it is used you need to also inject its own dependencies to where you are using. For example:

```
// auth.module.ts
@Module({
  // Mark it as a provider of auth module
  providers: [TokenService]
})
class AuthModule {}

// guard.ts
@Injectable()
class AuthGuard implements CanActive {
  // Use TokenService of AuthModule
  constructor(private tokenServie: TokenService) {}

  canActive() {
     return this.tokenServie.hasAccessToken();
  }
}

// user.controller.ts
@Controller('/users')
class UserController {
    constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

    @UseGuards(AuthGuard) // <- Use AuthGuard in UserModule, we need to inject TokenService which comes from AuthModule so that we need to import it
    getUsers() {
      return this.userService.getUsers();
    }
}

// user.module.ts
@Module({
   // AuthGuard uses TokenService and TokenService persisting in AuthModule. And we always need to import AuthModule wherever we use AuthGuard
  imports: [AuthModule], 
  controllers: [UserController]
})
class AuthModule {}
```

Here is my solution inspired by https://github.com/nestjs/passport

```
// stategy-storage.ts
const StragegyStorage = new Map();

// auth.strategy.ts
// Bundle injection at compile time
@Injectable()    
class AuthStrategy {
    constructor(private tokenServie: TokenService) {
        StragegyStorage.set(AuthStrategy.name, this);
    }
    verify(userId: string): Promise<boolean> {
      return this.tokenService.verify(userId);
    }
}

// guard.ts
@Injectable()
class AuthGuard implements CanActive {
  constructor() {}

  canActive() {
     const userId = ...
     // Get instance of strategy at runtime 
     return StragegyStorage.get(AuthStrategy.name).verify(userId);
  }
}

@Module({
  providers: [TokenService, AuthStrategy]
})
class AuthModule {}

// user.controller.ts
@Controller('/users')
class UserController {
    constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

    @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
    getUsers() {
      return this.userService.getUsers();
    }
}

// user.module.ts
@Module({
  // No need to import AuthModule anymore
  controllers: [UserController]
})
```

The thing here is we separate i**njecting module** into a separate class call strategy (AuthStrategy) at **compile time** and everything is injected correctly and **ready at runtime.**

At **runtime**, in AuthGuard, we just need to use it by getting from StrategyStorage.

That's it!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It really helped tie everything together after some experimentation and googling.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach without making the service global (so no `@Global`, and no `@Inject`) worked for me (on Nest 9)

### File Structure

```
├── app
│   └── app.module.ts        # main application module
├── status
│   ├── status.module.ts
│   └── status.service.ts    # status service (which is to be injected)
├── hodor
│   ├── hodor.decorators.ts  # avoid using @UseGuards(HodorGuard) => use @NotDangerousNow() instead
│   └── hodor.guard.ts       # the guard using StatusService
└── door
    ├── door.module.ts
    └── door.controller.ts   # the controller guarded by @NoDanger()
```

### AppModule

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core'
import { DoorModule } from '../door/door.module'
import { HodorGuard } from '../hodor/hodor.guard'
import { StatusModule } from '../status/status.module'

@Module({
  imports: [
    HodorModule,
    DoorModule,
    StatusModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_GUARD, useClass: HodorGuard } // makes the guard used everywhere
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### StatusModule

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { StatusService } from './status.service'

@Module({
    providers: [StatusService],
    exports: [StatusService]
})
export class StatusModule {}
```

### StatusService

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'

@Injectable()
export class StatusService {
    /**
     * Returns whether Hodor thinks it's dangerous at the given time.
     * Just async because in general there is a db call there.
     */
    async isDangerousAt(date: Date): Promise<boolean> {
        return date.getHours() > 22
    }
}
```

### hodor.decorators.ts

```js
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common'

export const DANGER_KEY = 'danger'

// 403 if Hodor thinks it's dangerous at the given date/time
// usage: @NotDangerous(date) => that's right I see no possible usage for that one, it's for the example
export const NotDangerous = (date: Date) => SetMetadata(DANGER_KEY, { date })

// 403 if Hodor thinks it's dangerous right now
// usage: @NotDangerousNow()
export const NotDangerousNow = () => SetMetadata(DANGER_KEY, { date: new Date() })
```

### hodor.guard.ts

```js
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ForbiddenException } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core'
import { DANGER_KEY } from './hodor.decorator'
import { StatusService } from '../status/status.service'

type HodorMetadata = {
    status: PlatformHodor
    expected: boolean
}

@Injectable()
export class HodorGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private reflector: Reflector,
        private readonly statusService: StatusService // Do not use @Inject (or nest won't be able to inject it)
    ) {}

    /**
     * Rely on status service to check if Hodor thinks it is dangerous at the given date/time.
     * @throws ForbiddenException if Hodor thinks it's dangerous at the given date/time => 403
     */
    async canActivate(context: any): Promise<boolean> {
        // METADATA DANGER_KEY is the magic link between NotDangerous decorator and the guard
        const metadata = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<HodorMetadata>(
            DANGER_KEY,
            [context.getHandler(), context.getClass()]
        )

        // because we inject the guard in the whole app
        // => it must let pass in routes with no decorator
        if (!metadata) return true

        // 403 if dangerous
        const isDangerous = await this.statusService.isDangerousAt(metadata.date)
        if (isDangerous) {
            throw new ForbiddenException(`Hodor thinks it's dangerous on ${metadata.date}`)
        }
        
        // let pass otherwise
        return true
    }
}
```

### DoorModule

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { DoorController } from './door.controller'

@Module({
    controllers: [DoorController],
    providers: [DoorService],
})
export class DoorModule {}
```

### DoorService

```js
import { Controller, HttpCode, Post } from '@nestjs/common'
import { NotDangerousNow } from '../hodor/hodor.decorator'

@Controller('door')
export class DoorController {
    @NotDangerousNow()
    @Post()
    open(): Promise<string> {
        return 'please, come in'
    }
}
```