# What would be the best way to create an isAuthor guard for nestjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, middleware

I have been taking online course from udemy and playing around with the `guard` `middleware`

I also created the `admin.guard` `auth.guard` suggested by following the tutorial but I am thinking what if I want to add an `isAuthor.guard` that not only the admin can make changes to `post` or whatever but the original author is also able to make edits...

What would be a better way to create this?  Should it be a guard? or middleware would be better?

P.S. I tried accessing services through guard with this post [Inject service into guard in Nest.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862644/inject-service-into-guard-in-nest-js) but didn't work for me.

Edit: Also, is it possible to have or guards?
For example `isAdmin` / `isAuthor` so it can be used flexible instead of having a `isAdminOrAuthor`

Thanks in advance for any suggestions / advices.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is the best way, but this one is one that seems practical (it is applicable to the larger scope than just isAdmin/isAuthor case). NOTE: If only isAdmin isAuthor case is needed, please move appropriate logic from PostRelationResolver up to RolesGuard and skip a whole generic approach.

A generic approach is provided here because it allows covering a far, far wider range of cases, that are of the same nature (there are users and any specific entity - relationship-based restriction needs to be applied).

So, to cover it.

Suppose that reading posts (just as an example) is restricted in a way that the Admin can see all of them and the author can see only their own posts.

It can be implemented like this:

```
  @Get('read-post/:postId')
  @UseGuards(RolesGuard)
  @SetMetadata('general-roles', [GeneralRole.ADMIN])
  @SetMetadata('relation-roles', [RelationRole.POST_AUTHOR])
  readPostAsAuthor(
    @Param('postId') postId: number,
  ) {
    return this.postRepository.findPostById(postId);
  }
```

And for a listing of posts, something like this:

```
  @Get('read-all-posts')
  async readAllPosts(
    @Req() request
  ) {
    const posts = await this.postRepository.findAll();
    return this.rbacService.filterList(
      request, 
      posts, 
      [GeneralRole.ADMIN], 
      [RelationRole.POST_AUTHOR]
    );
  }
```

Note for listing filter: One should make sure that implementation doesn't even respond with unallowed posts and this filter should be only utilized as backup (since the request doesn't contain enough information to restrict call).

For this to work, RolesGuard implementation is needed:

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Reflector } from "@nestjs/core";
import { GeneralRole } from "../role/general-role";
import { RelationRole } from "../role/relation-role";
import { RbacService } from "../rbac.service";

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private reflector: Reflector,
    private rbacService: RbacService,
  ) {
  }
  
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const contextHandler = context.getHandler();
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    
    const requestedGeneralRoles = this.reflector.get<GeneralRole[]>('general-roles', contextHandler);
    const requestedRelationRoles = this.reflector.get<RelationRole[]>('relation-roles', contextHandler);

    return this.rbacService.authorize(request, requestedGeneralRoles, requestedRelationRoles);
  }
}
```

The logic for actual authorization is contained in rbacService, given here:

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { GeneralRole } from "./role/general-role";
import { RelationRole } from "./role/relation-role";
import { UserRepository } from "./repository/user.repository";
import { CoreRelationResolver } from "./relation-resolver/core.relation-resolver";

@Injectable()
export class RbacService {

  constructor(
    private userRepository: UserRepository,
    private coreRelationResolver: CoreRelationResolver,
  ) {
  }

  // NOTE: This method should be implemented however token to user mapping is done - based on business requirement.
  async getUserByToken(token: string) {
    return await this.userRepository.findByToken(token);
  }

  async authorize(request: any, requestedGeneralRoles: GeneralRole[], requestedRelationRoles: RelationRole[]) {
    const user = await this.getUserByToken(request.headers['token']);

    if (!user) {
      return false;
    }

    if (requestedGeneralRoles && requestedGeneralRoles.indexOf(user.role) !== -1) {
      // If user is of general role, it is simply allowed - regardless of relationRoles.
      return true;
    }
    
    // Relation roles handling (user is not ADMIN - for example - but is author of post)
    if (requestedRelationRoles) {
      const relationRoles = await this.coreRelationResolver.getRelationRoles(user, requestedRelationRoles, request);
      return this.isAllowed(requestedRelationRoles, relationRoles);
    }

    return false;
  }
  
  isAllowed(requestedRelationRoles: RelationRole[], containingRelationRoles: RelationRole[]) {
    const matches = containingRelationRoles.filter(sr => {
      return !!requestedRelationRoles.find(rr => rr === sr);
    });

    return !!matches.length;
  }

  async filterList(
    request: any, 
    entities: any[], 
    requestedGeneralRoles: GeneralRole[], 
    requestedRelationRoles: RelationRole[]
  ): Promise<any[]> {
    const user = await this.getUserByToken(request.headers['token']);

    if (!user) {
      return [];
    }

    if (requestedGeneralRoles && requestedGeneralRoles.indexOf(user.role) !== -1) {
      return entities;
    }

    const result = [];
    const relationResolver = await this.coreRelationResolver.findRelationResolver(requestedRelationRoles);
    
    for (const entity of entities) {
      const singleEntityRelations = await relationResolver.getRelations(user, entity);
      if (this.isAllowed(requestedRelationRoles, singleEntityRelations)) {
        result.push(entity);
      } else {
        console.warn("WARNING: Check next entity and query that responds with it. It shouldn't be here!");
        console.warn(entity);
      }
    }
    
    return result;
  }
}
```

Allow me to provide a small description here before proceeding with the rest of the logic.

Authorization logic stops in RbacService.

CoreRelationResolver service is all about recognizing relations between the User that utilizes the application (makes a request) and the entity that is an object of the given operation (upon which operation is executed).

Possible relations between Users and specific entities are described with RelationalRoles. With RelationalRoles restriction is defined as: "only AUTHOR and COLLABORATOR of given Post can see it".

CoreRelationResolver implementation is provided here:

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { RelationRole } from "../role/relation-role";
import { IRelationResolver } from "./i-relation-resolver";
import { PostRelationResolver } from "./post.relation-resolver";
import { UserEntity } from "../entity/user.entity";
import { ClientAppRelationResolver } from "./client-app.relation-resolver";

@Injectable()
export class CoreRelationResolver {

  private relationResolvers: IRelationResolver<UserEntity, unknown>[];

  constructor(
    private postRelationAuthorization: PostRelationResolver,
    private clientAppRelationResolver: ClientAppRelationResolver,
  ) {
    this.relationResolvers = [
      this.postRelationAuthorization,
      this.clientAppRelationResolver,
    ];
  }

  async getRelationRoles(user: UserEntity, requiredRelations: RelationRole[], request: any): Promise<RelationRole[]> {
    let relationRoles = [];

    const relationResolver = await this.findRelationResolver(requiredRelations);
    
    if (relationResolver) {
      const relatedObject = await relationResolver.getRelatedObject(request);

      if (relatedObject) {
        relationRoles = await relationResolver.getRelations(user, relatedObject);
      }
    }

    return relationRoles;
  }

  async findRelationResolver(requiredRelations: RelationRole[]): Promise<IRelationResolver<UserEntity, unknown>> {
    let result = null;
    
    for (const relationResolver of this.relationResolvers) {
      const supportedRelations = await relationResolver.getSupportedRelations();

      const matches = supportedRelations.filter(sr => {
        return !!requiredRelations.find(rr => rr === sr);
      });

      if (matches.length) {
        result = relationResolver;
        break;
      }
    }
    
    return result;
  }
}
```

It is designed in a way that in its constructor any RelationResolver (IRelationResolver interface) should be registered and properly implemented.

IRelationResolver interface:

```
import { RelationRole } from "../role/relation-role";

/**
 * T - Type of user
 * U - Type of relatedObject
 */
export interface IRelationResolver<T, U> {
  /**
   * Return RelationRoles that this resolver is responsible to handle.
   */
  getSupportedRelations(): Promise<RelationRole[]>;

  /**
   * Retrieve related object from the request data.
   */
  getRelatedObject(request: any): Promise<U>;

  /**
   * Calculate and provide relation between user and related object.
   */
  getRelations(user: T, relatedObject: U): Promise<RelationRole[]>;
}
```

And finally, retrieving the related object and recognizing the relation between the user and the given object, is implemented here:

```
import { IRelationResolver } from "./i-relation-resolver";
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { RelationRole } from "../role/relation-role";
import { UserEntity } from "../entity/user.entity";
import { PostEntity } from "../entity/post.entity";
import { PostRepository } from "../repository/post.repository";

@Injectable()
export class PostRelationResolver implements IRelationResolver<UserEntity, PostEntity> {
  constructor(
    private postRepository: PostRepository
  ) {
  }
  
  async getSupportedRelations(): Promise<RelationRole[]> {
    return [RelationRole.POST_AUTHOR];
  }

  async getRelatedObject(request: any): Promise<PostEntity> {
    const postId: string = request.params.postId;
  
    return await this.postRepository.findPostById(parseInt(postId));
  }

  async getRelations(user: UserEntity, relatedObject: PostEntity): Promise<RelationRole[]> {
    const relations = [];
    
    if (relatedObject.authorId === user.id) {
      relations.push(RelationRole.POST_AUTHOR);
    }
    
    return relations;
  }
}
```

Obviously, freedom is to implement here whatever is needed and however the relationship is defined.

For all next RBAC cases (for different entity types), one should create RelationResolver, implement it, and register it in the constructor of CoreRelationResolver.

All in all, considering the usability range, this approach should be flexible enough to be applied to many RBAC scenarios (and please consider it conceptual - there are no robustness features added).