# Nest.js - injecting service to a global guard

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a global guard which is registered like this in main.ts:

```
app.useGlobalGuards(new CheckUserGuard());
```

however, inside this guard, I need to get the id of the logged user and then, using another service, I have to check something related to him in the database, basically like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class CheckUserGuard {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const { req } = ctx.getContext();

    if(this.userService.isFine(req.user)) return true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Problem is, how can I pass the userService into the constructor to be able to use it? userService is also depended on some other services

Comment: that works as long as `UserService` is available on all modules as well

Comment: This will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862644/inject-service-into-guard-in-nest-js

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use `app.useGlobalGuards()` where you have to pass the instance of the guard(s) yourself, why not make use of the `APP_GUARD` provider and let Nest take care of the DI for you?

```js
@Module({
  imports: [...moduleImports],
  controllers: [...moduleControllers],
  providers: [
    ...moduleProviders,
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: CheckUserGuard,
    },
  },
})
export class FeatureModule {}
```

This makes the guard a globally bound guard, and you get the benefit of dependency injection from Nest. So long as the `UserService` is available in the context of module where the guard is defined, this approach works flawlessly, and can even lead to less set up in your tests because of not needing to call `useGlobalGuards()` again.

Personally, I like to add these global enhancers to the `AppModule`, but you may want to put them where they make sense for your application.

Answer (score 0):

To inject a service out of the module you can use `app.get`(for more you can see the official docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications)

```
@Injectable()
class SomeService {
  doSomething() {
    Logger.log('HELLO FROM SERVICE');
  }
}

@Module({
  providers: [SomeService],
  exports: [SomeService],
})
class SomeModule {}

@Module({
  imports: [SomeModule],
})
export class AppModule {}

@Injectable()
class SomeGuard {
  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}

  canActivate() {
    this.someService.doSomething();
    return true;
  }
}

const bootstrap = async () => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.useGlobalGuards(new SomeGuard(app.get(SomeService)));

  await app.listen(process.env.APP_LISTEN_PORT);
};

bootstrap();
```